# After adding cocoapods to a mature react-native project, my app archives as a separate app rather than an update to my existing app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I recently upgraded from RN0.51.0 to RN 0.55.4. I was using react-native-mixpanel-bridge for analytics but it stopped working now that I upgraded to RN0.55.4. The library I am replacing it with (react-native-mixpanel) requires the use of cocoapods. After some upgrading struggles, the app is running fine on a simulator but when I try to archive it it from the .xcworkspace it shows up as a new app rather than an update to my existing app. Before this upgrade we were opening .xcodeproj in xcode and archiving from there.

Previously the application identifier was XXXXXX.com.projectName.app.ios.triplets
Now the application identifier is XXXXXX.org.reactjs.native.example.projectName

Is the application identifier what determines if an archive is an update to an existing app or an entirely new app? If so, how do I change it to match the application identifier of my original app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change application identifier you should open your project in xCode and change bundle identifier in the general tab of project settings

[image: xCode ui]